# Database restoring in Marklogic

Tags: marklogic, database-restore, marklogic-8

We are using Marklogic 8.0-4 version.

I have a database backup from MarkLogic database. I want to restore it to a new database name on the same server. It is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of the new database needs to match the configuration from the backup.  [Create a new database by copying the configuration from an existing database](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/maintenance#id_55729)

Then use the [admin api](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/maintenance#id_74348) `xdmp:database-restore` to restore the backup, specifying the new database name.

I haven't had a chance to test this, so I'm not sure of the exact details, but this should get you pointed in the right direction.